# KnockoutJS: Add Property to ViewModel through Custom Binding

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm adding a custom binding to my page.  Within it, I'd like to save one of the objects I create as a property of the viewModel.  When I do this, I get "undefined" when I try and access it outside of the binding.  Why?  Here is a reduced down example:

HTML:

```
<div id = "myDiv" data-bind = "fooAdd: myFoo"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fooAdd = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var foo = 1;
    viewModel._foo = foo;
  }
};

var ViewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.myFoo = ko.observable({});
  console.log(self); //Here I can expand the object returned in 
                     //the console and see that _foo is equal to 1.
  console.log(self._foo); //returns undefined
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you would expect `_foo` to be set before your constructor completes? The reason why you can "expand" the object in the console and see `_foo` is because you are printing the entire object (which gets kept up to date by most debuggers) so in the few milliseconds after it logs the custom binding gets applied and the property is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sample, you're setting the new property in the init, which gets called only at the time of applying the bindings, but you are trying to access it in the constructor of the view model. Try `console.log(viewmodel._foo)` after the applyBindings call.

Comment: Changing the last few lines to:
`myView=new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(myView);
    myView._foo;`
worked.  I get it now.  Thanks